# No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘0’

Tags: haskell

My code:

```
divisibleBy :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divisibleBy x y
    | mod x y == 0 = True
    | otherwise = False

isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven x
    | (divisibleBy x 2) == 0 = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Error:

```
practical1.hs:30:28: error:
    • No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘0’
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘0’
      In the expression: (divisibleBy x 2) == 0
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘isEven’:
        (divisibleBy x 2) == 0
   |
30 |     | (divisibleBy x 2) == 0 = True    |
```

The `divisibleBy` function works, but the `isEven` one doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the type and definition of `divisibleBy`, and identify when it can *ever* return `0` (instead of `True` or `False`). Haskell `Bool` is just as distinct from `Int` as it is from `IO Char` or any other type.

Comment: Put `isEven x = mod x 2 == 0`, erase the rest.

Answer (score 5):

Well the error message already says this. You write:

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven x
    | (divisibleBy x 2) == 0 = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Now if we typecheck this, we see that `(divisibleBy x 2)` will return a `Bool`, and you cannot perform a `(==)` with a `Bool` and a number (a `Bool` is in Haskell *not* a number).

Why you write this with `== 0` is not really clear for me, we can write it as:

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven x
    | (divisibleBy x 2) = True
    | otherwise = False
```

But now it is still inelegant: we do not have to check if a condition holds to return `True` and otherwise `False`, we can simply return the definition, so:

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven x = divisibleBy x 2
```

Or we can omit the `x` parameter, by using `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`:

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven = flip divisibleBy 2
```

The same holds for the `divisibleBy` function, we can rewrite it to:

```
divisibleBy :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divisibleBy x y = mod x y == 0
```

Or without parameters:

```
divisibleBy :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divisibleBy = ((0 ==) .) . mod
```

## Swapping the parameters of `divisableBy`

It looks however more *Haskell* to *swap* the parameters of the function, so we can write it as:

```
divisibleBy :: Int -> Int -> Bool
divisibleBy x y = mod y x == 0
```

Since now we can define a function `divisibleBy 2`, that will check for any parameter whether that number is divisible by two.

In that case, the `isEven` function, looks like:

```
isEven :: Int -> Bool
isEven = divisibleBy 2
```

Comment: For `isEven x = flip divisibleBy 2`, you just need `isEven = ...` right?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: correct, thanks for spotting this :)

Comment: Even so, I prefer the previous version. It is clearer to read and less characters to type.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: yeah. like the French say: "*les goûts et les couleurs ne se discutent pas*" :)

Comment: It actually makes more sense for `divisibleBy` to take its arguments in the other order. Then `divisibleBy 2` is, in fact, a function that tests if its argument is divisible by 2, rather than a function that tests if 2 is divisible by its argument.

Comment: @chepner: correct, usually Haskell uses the opposite order of arguments than with for instance objected oriented programming. Whereas in OO, one would write `x.foo(bar, qux)`, usually in Haskell it is `foo bar qux x`.

Comment: @chepner Alternatively, you can write `x \`divisibleBy\` 2` which reads better than `divisibleBy x 2`.

Comment: Although using it as an infix operator is a strong argument for the original order :)

Comment: Moral of the story: naming things is hard.